# How can I pass a struct and an int from an function and back to main? C

Tags: c

I am trying to return back the array persons and the quantity_persons_count to main() but I cant get it to work. I have tried changing void to int and person but that obv doesnt work.

```
struct person{..}
int main(){
 int o;
 int quantity_persons_count = 0;
 struct person persons[100];

 while(1){

    printf("1.Add a new person");
    scanf("%i",&o);

    switch(o)
    {
        case 1: AddPerson(persons,quantity_persons_count);
                break;
}

void AddPerson(struct person *persons, int quantity_persons_count){
 if(quantity_persons_count == 100){
    printf("ERROR.\n");
 }
 else{
     printf("name\n");
     scanf("%s",persons[quantity_persons_count+1].name);
     quantity_persons_count++;
     printf("done\n");

}

}
```

Comment: Not knowing the declaration, `scanf("%s",&persons[quantity_persons_count+1].name);` seems invoking *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type. if `persons[quantity_persons_count+1].name` is an array of `char`, the `&` should be removed.

Comment: What is the array to return back? How do you call this function from `main()` and how do you test it? Consider posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: What you may want to know is [Parameters are passed by value](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/1006/function-parameters/10900/parameters-are-passed-by-value#t=20160820014330354564).

Comment: You could pack them both in a `struct` and return *that* to `main()` ...

Comment: You may want to have a look at your nesting of brackets in the `switch`. Your example won't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want changes to `quantity_persons_count` to be visible in `main`, you need to pass a pointer to it:

```
void AddPerson(struct person *persons, int *quantity_persons_count){

     if(*quantity_persons_count == 100){
        printf("ERROR.\n");
     }
     else{
         printf("name\n");
         scanf("%s",persons[*quantity_persons_count+1].name);
         (*quantity_persons_count)++;
         printf("done\n");

    }

}
```

Then you call it like this:

```
AddPerson(persons,&quantity_persons_count);
```

Comment: @anon You need to change the function prototype to match the definition.